# I want to rsync files older than 2 days, syncs all files instead

Tags: backup, rsync

I run a game server with a plugin that put hourly server backups in /backups. After 1 day the plugin saves 2 backups/day and deletes the rest. I want to sync this backup directory to a remote server but only for files older than 2 days so that it doesn't sync files that eventually will be deleted by the end of the day.

To do that I run this:

```
find /path/backups/ -type f -mtime 2 -exec rsync -vPhd -e "ssh -p 512" /path/backups/ --delete --ignore-existing me@host:/remote/path/server-backups/ \;
```

This causes all files in /backups/ to be synced to /server-backups/ instead of files older than 2 days. How would I resolv this issue?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: I guess you need to change your exec command.

Comment: Try repacing rsync by scp and use `{}`. Here you don't pass the result of your find command to the rsync command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Natim is correct in that {} needs to be used to pass on the filenames to rsync. There is no need to switch to scp. Just use the {} with rsync as in:

```
find /path/backups/ -type f -mtime +2 -exec rsync -vPhd -e "ssh -p 512" {} --delete --ignore-existing me@host:/remote/path/server-backups/ \;
```

Note: I also changed

```
-mtime 2
```

to

```
-mtime +2
```

as you state files older than 2 days. You may need to tune this to your exact needs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It now syncs files older than 2 days as intended. As a side note, is --delete used correctly? It doesn't delete files on target when when local directory is updated.

Comment: yes that's because the {} passes on the files and not the directory as such. so by definition there is nothing to delete and you could actually skip the --delete. if you really want you could delete files on target straight before the rsync. I would not recommend this as when something goes wrong on source you will loose files the files on target as well. I would recommend to keep the above statement (arguably without the --delete that doesn't do anything) and implement a separate cleanup script on target. Depending on your reply I'' adjust my answer :).